# Monger database connecting and storing the results

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

So I have a database of posts I want to access, but I also want to cache the results of the query so I'm not making extra connections to the database.

So far I have something like

```
 ;;talk with the database and get posts by their [count]
 (defn posts-from-db []
   (let [conn (mg/connect {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 27272})
         db (mg/get-db conn "submitted-content")
         coll "posts"]
     (with-collection db coll
     (find {})
     (fields [:post_content :id])
     ;; it is VERY IMPORTANT to use array maps with sort
     (sort (array-map :tags -1 :post_content 1))
     (limit numberOfPosts))))
```

This returns a collection of results that look like

```
({:_id #<ObjectId 54d927ce9c521eb276553f11>, :post_content "Mermaids and dakinis "},
 { .... },
 { .... },
 { .... })
```

I think a good way to do this is to store the result in a symbol (var? key? .. not sure what the appropriate verbiage is for Clojure) and then check if that var is set.

How does a developer normally address this situation?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to add a cache layer, you can look at the library [core.memoize](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize)